# Why when I open terminal do I see the following:

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, anaconda

```
Last login: Mon Jun 17 10:41:49 on ttys000
-bash: export: `2019.03': not a valid identifier
XXX:~ YYY$
```

(Note the XXXs and YYYs are just replacement)

Specifically, I am talking about the 
-bash: export: `2019.03': not a valid identifier
I just installed Anaconda on Mac and then tried to update it and did in it incorrectly and now when I open the terminal, this appears every time. I know that 2019.03 is the current version of Anaconda and I have since fixed Anaconda so that my version is currently that version but I do not know what this "not a valid identifier" this is. Any help with how to address what it is, why it is there, and how I can remove it would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for assistance. I opened the bash profile and some of the comments was in the same line as the export path line and that was messing it up. Thank you!

Comment: Check your dot files like `.profile`

Comment: somewhere in your bash dot files, it looks like you have `export $VAR` instead of `export VAR`

Comment: If your problem is solved, either delete the question (if it was solved in a way that wasn't likely to help others -- probably the case here), or use the "Add an Answer" button to add an answer, which you can (after a timeout) select. Otherwise, the question shows up as needing solutions until it's marked either closed or answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the terminal and see that there is some error coming from ~bash, it likely has something to do with the bash profile. You should open that up and check to make sure that nothing is out of place like having more than one thing on the same line since it can be sensitive to that.

Answer (score 0):

You see the following due to the anaconda3 2019.03 installer trying to export a non valid identifier from your .bash_profile file. Note, this file is usually hidden due to the period in front of the file name.

The following is what was appearing in my terminal:

```
-bash: export: `2019.03': not a valid identifier
```

Do the following to fix this issue.

```
$ nano .bash_profile
```

Now you should be inside of the .bash_profile file using the nano editor.

```
# comment out or remove the following line from .bash_profile 
# then save before you exit the file
#export PATH="MAMP_PHP:$PATH"# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
```

Close your terminal and open it again, and the annoying "-bash: export: `2019.03': not a valid identifier" should be gone whenever you open a new terminal.